# Am I too fast to count jiffies?

Tags: c++, linux, procfs

I do some local experiments on different database systems. I collect (sum up) CPU information from `/proc/status` before and after I execute a query. The difference should tell me the amount of jiffies or USER_HZ during query runtime. But the difference is zero when (according to `clock_gettime()`) a query has a runtime somewhere below `0.001 seconds`. Is this to fast to utilize the CPU information or am I missing something else?

Comment: `clock_gettime` has nanosecond resolution on most machines, or at least microsecond. I use it all the time for measuring time and never get zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jiffy, as of Linux kernel 2.6.0, is 1/250 of a second, or 0.004 seconds [see [time(7)]](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/time.7.html). You'll never get a smaller resolution than that.

I recommend you use the `rdtsc` instruction, which is likely available as a compiler intrinsic. This is incremented every 1 CPU tick, so by dividing by the frequency you can get the amount of time that passed. You can also implement it [with inline assembly](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~kazutomo/rdtsc.html).

It's actually a bit ridiculous to be checking `/proc/status` because there's a good chance that opening the file descriptor and reading the contents will actually take longer than your query did to execute. `rdtsc` is much more reliable.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. Usually my queries run some orders of magnitude longer. So I hope the access overhead to `/proc` can be ignored for a sufficient approximation of cpu utilization. I'll take this as an evaluation of my measuring process: it does not even take a jiffy :P

Comment: Honestly, it's not hard to switch to `rdtsc`.

Comment: My Machine does somewhat around 80 on the first example (Haven't figured out how to pass the mentioned parameter to g++ through eclipse, yet). I'd have never expected that inline assembly is only this few steps away.

Comment: Brought it down to 55 (Actually eclipse has a gui for optimization level...)

Comment: Find a number that works, then just subtract that from your reading before dividing by the frequency to get the most accurate value. But in reality, it doesn't matter: 55 is 0.000000022916 seconds if you're on a modest 2.4GHz processor. In other words: nothing. This is a ridiculously high-precision counter.

Comment: I added my experimental C++ code on `rdtsc` to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/11366/13029) for revision and sharing.

Comment: `clock_gettime` is not limited to this resolution. It will be using the TSC register as well and should provide high precision times.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y I never said it was. I said `/proc/status` jiffies are.

Comment: Finally I'll keep parsing `/proc/status` because the distinction between total jiffies, Idle jiffies and IO-wait jiffies is very valuable to my database experiments. It's even possible to count jiffies of a specific process.